# Order of sess.run([op1, op2...]) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wonder what's the running order of the op list in sess.run(ops_list, ...). for example:
  for a typical classification scenario: `_, loss = sess.run([train_op, loss_op])`, if `train_op` run first,then the loss is the loss after current backprop. But if `loss` run first, then the loss is the loss before current backprop.
  anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`loss` will be the value of the loss *before* the update caused by `train_op`. Note that `loss_op` is an input to the optimizer, so it necessarily goes "before" `train_op` in the graph. `loss_op` is computed with the variable values *at the beginning* of the `run` operation. If you wanted to compute the loss *after* `train_op`, you could do that for example using a [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) block with the optimizer and computing the loss again, but in that case you would be doing two forward passes of your model on each step, with the associated cost. Usually, if you just want to plot the loss for monitorization or something like that it is okay to use the value from the previous step.

For further explanation, in general the order in which TensorFlow operations are executed is only guaranteed to the extent that these operations depend on each other, and it is not related to the order in which the are passed to `run`. In your case, `train_op` depends on `loss_op`, so `loss_op` has to go first. However, in other cases operations do not depend directly on each other, and in that case the order is not guaranteed. Many times that does not really matter, but in some cases it does. Consider the next example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable(0)
v2 = 2 * v
v_update = v.assign(v + 1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        print(sess.run([v_update, v2]))
```

A run in my computer produced this output:

```
[1, 0]
[2, 2]
[3, 4]
[4, 8]
[5, 10]
```

As you see, `v2` is sometimes twice the updated value and sometimes twice the non-updated value. If for example we wanted to make sure that `v2` always runs *before* `v_update` we could do:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v = tf.Variable(0)
v2 = 2 * v
with tf.control_dependencies([v2]):
    v_update = v.assign(v + 1)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        print(sess.run([v_update, v2]))
```

Which consistently produces:

```
[1, 0]
[2, 2]
[3, 4]
[4, 6]
[5, 8]
```