# What is the sequence for tensorflow's session to run a list of tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

See the code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
op = tf.assign(x, x + 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print(sess.run([x, op]))
```

There are two possible results:

- x=1 and op=2
- x=2 and op=2

They depend on the order of evaluation, for the first case, `x` is evaluated before `op`, and for the second case, `x` is evaluated after `op`.

I have run the code many times, but the result is always `x=2 and op=2`. So I guess that `tensorflow` can guarantee `x` is evaluated after `op`. Is it right? And how does `tensorflow` guarantee the dependence?

### Update

For the case above, the result is determinate. But in the follow case, the result is not determinate.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1)
op = tf.assign(x, x + 1)
x = x + 0                   # add this line

with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  for i in range(5):
    print(sess.run([x, op]))
```

In the first code, `x` is `Variable` and `op` depends on `x`, so `x` is always evaluated after `op`. But in the second case, `x` becomes `Tensor`, and `op` depend on `Variable x`(After `x = x + 0`, x is overrided). So the `op` doesn't depend on `Tensor x`.

Comment: Practically duplicate of [Order of sess.run(\[op1, op2…\]) in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53165418), although this one may be more generally stated.

Comment: @jdehesa In my opinion, the node having longer path (include other node path) will be evaluated first.

Comment: Technically, the first case is indeterminate too. Like you said, "`x` is `Variable` and `op` depends on `x`", but that means `x` must necessarily be evaluated _before_ `op`, not after. However, `x`, being a variable, will usually return the updated value if it is assigned in the run (I don't know if this is actually guaranteed to be the case, but it is what I have seen in general). However, values that depend on a variable (like `x + 0` in your second example) do not necessarily use the most updated value, and that is why you can see the indeterministic output.

Answer (score 2):

The order in which tensors are evaluated is undefined. See [the API docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) (towards, the very bottom, in the "Returns" info on `Session.run()`). As such, you should not rely on them being executed in a particular order. If you need to guarantee an order you should probably use separate `run` calls for the different tensors/ops.

Comment: You can also use [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to enforce relative order between ops.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1), dtype=tf.int32)
    x = tf.Variable(1)

    op = tf.assign(x, x+1)
    with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
        x = x + 0
        # x = tf.multiply(x, 3)
        # x = tf.add(x, 0)
```

but not always:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1), dtype=tf.int32)
    x = tf.Variable(1)
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):  # add this line.
    op = tf.assign(x, x+1)
    with tf.control_dependencies([op]):
        x = x + 0
        # x = tf.multiply(x, 3)
        # x = tf.add(x, 0)
```

I think the problem is from:

1. Some operation (like `x = x + 0`, **read** value from the `Variable` and then add 0) depends on the value of the `Variable`, while the `Variable` is changed by some assign operation (like op = tf.assign(x, x+1)). If there are no dependencies, these two operations are parallel. So when reading the value of `Variable`, it is not sure whether `assign` is already done.
2. transferring data from different devices. Even there are dependencies, it is still indeterminate.

In brief, if all variables and operations are in the same device, then `with tf.control_dependencies` [should guarantee](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependencies) that op is before the add operation.

Note that:

(these notes below are not important but might help you)

1. `tf.assign` operations only update the `Variable`, not `Tensor`.
2. When you do `x=x+0`, the new `x` becomes a `Tensor`; but the `op = tf.assign(x, x+1)` returns the ref of `Variable`. So `op` should always be determinate because it depends on the current value of `Variable` which will not be changed by other operations.
3. GPU does not support int32 variable. When I run your code snippet on my machine (tf-gpu1.12), variable is created on CPU but ops are done on GPU. You can check the variables and ops by `config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)`.